# How to add contact details next to responsive Google Map

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, responsive-design

Sorry if this is basic but I've been trying to add the contact details next to the google map. But they end up displaying below the map, instead of next to them. What am i missing? really appreciate your help!

This is how it currently looks:

[image: Current Display]

HTML:

```
    <div class="span9">
        <div class="map-responsive">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d386950.6511603643!2d-73.70231446529533!3d40.738882125234106!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNueva+York!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sus!4v1445032011908" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
    </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="contact-details">
                <h3>Contact Details</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">hello@hello.com</a></li>
                    <li>(916) 375-2525</li>
                    <li>
                        NY City meet
                        <br>
                        NY City
                        <br>
                        USA
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.map-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.map-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:80%;
    width:50%;
    position:absolute;
}


.contact-details h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact-details ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;   
}

.contact-details ul li {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap??

Comment: Yes..i'm using a bootstrap template.

Comment: which version are you using?? please let me know..

Comment: Please update your version to 3.3.6

Comment: I'm unfortunately using a set template, migrating to v3 would involve a lot of work. Is it possible to work it out within the current version?

Comment: Sure please check my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used bootstrap version 2.3.1

Check [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq1q3a1L/1/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">

  <div class="span9">
    <div class="map-responsive">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d386950.6511603643!2d-73.70231446529533!3d40.738882125234106!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNueva+York!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sus!4v1445032011908" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <div class="contact-details">
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            hello@hello.com
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>(916) 375-2525</li>
        <li>
          NY City meet
          <br>
          NY City
          <br>
          USA
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: They are still showing up below one another in the my Fiddle screen. Can we make them look display next to each other? 9 col of map and 3 col of details?

Comment: try using `col-xs-9` and `col-xs-3` instead

Comment: Yep! It would be great if this can be worked out within v2.3.1, since switching for me would be a big hassle now

Comment: @chris it works fine please check updated fiddle and let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Sunil! <3 this community.

Comment: Your Welcome @chris happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all `<div>` tag automatically include `display: block` style in the element, so it will make the element displayed full width even if the element isn't. So what you need to do is add `float: left` within each of the div container.

Comment: adding float:left within the css of the map didnt seem to help. Did i understand it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Update the position as per requirements**

```
.contact-details ul li {
position:absolute;
left:300px;
top:20px;
margin: 0 0 20px;
line-height: 28px;
padding: 0; 
}
```